# Map a Midi controller to Calf plugins

Tags: linux, plugin, midi

How do I map a Midi CC signal to a Calf plugin in Ardour.

The default in Ardour is to hold CTRL and press the mouse wheel button to asign a Hardware knob to the software knob.

How does it work with the Calf studio gear plugins?